# Use portable class library in windows phone project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, portable-class-library

I have made a portable class library in visual studio 2013 and I want to use it in a windows phone 7 project that I that I have made using visual studio 2012.
But I don't know and not getting how to use it in windows phone 7 project.

But I have added it like a existing project to my WP 7 project and then tried to add a reference to it but it is throwing an error.

[image]

Comment: You should try to create your PCL project on VS2012 (VS2013 doesn't support WP7)

Comment: but in that case My pcl project not able download nuget package of httpclient,bcl.async , Threading.Tasks that is why i go to vs 2013.

Comment: Have you tried to update your nuget package manager for vs 2012? Tools > Extension and updates > Nuget Package Manager > Select the update tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your portable class library targeting, and which version of Windows Phone is your project targeting?  You can get that error message if the PCL doesn't support the version of Windows Phone you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @**Daniel Plaisted** and @**Olivier Payen** You both are right. So, What i have done is i removed **WP7** support from my PCL and Update its support to **WP 7.5 and higher** and keep all other target same.Now i am able to install nuget package required to my PCL.
Cheers !!

EDIT:-
Hi this error comes again when i made project in visual studio 2012 and try to add a reference that is present only in lower version of .Net Frameworks.During adding a reference a warning message comes below of adding reference windows that shows if you add this reference then .Net version of this application will be changed to lower version.I had ignored the warning first time so does this error comes.
This is just for the information hope it help someone.